# Regular expression in Bash filter

Tags: regex, bash

i have this string

```
<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:6px;'>Displaying Result 1 - 10 of 10 Matching Services</div>
```

I need the number "10" after "of"

My Regex is now

```
if [[ "$WARNING" =~ "of.([0-9]*)" ]]
then
        echo "OK: $WARNING"
else
    echo "NOK: $WARNING"
fi
```

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to quote the rhs of `=~`.
2. You can use the `BASH_REMATCH` variable to get the desired value.

Try:

```
if [[ "$WARNING" =~ of.([0-9]*) ]]
then
    echo "OK: $WARNING"
else
    echo "NOK: $WARNING"
fi

echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables):

> `BASH_REMATCH`
>
> An array variable whose members are assigned by the `=~` binary operator to the `[[` conditional command (see Conditional Constructs).
>   The element with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the
>   entire regular expression. The element with index n is the portion of
>   the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression. This variable
>   is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions. Just use bash's built-in [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
$ x="<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:6px;'>Displaying Result 1 - 10 of 10 Matching Services</div>"
$ x="${x##*of }"
$ echo "${x%% *}"
10
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another just for fun `awk` example, you can modify it to supply the `WARNING`

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:6px;'>Displaying Result 1 - 10 of 10 Matching Services</div>
[[bash_prompt$]]$ awk '/of [0-9]*/{l=gensub(/^.*of ([0-9]*).*$/,"\\1",1); if(l > 10) print "greater"; else print "smaller"}' log
smaller
```